# how to use php in javascript if statement

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  var needToConfirm = true;

  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    if (needToConfirm)
    {

      return  'Are you sure?';


     }
     else 
     return 'Continue';
  }
```

here needToConfirm is just a flag/a variable. What I want, is to insert a php statement in the if condition and execute the php statement when the condition is true. Can anyone help me??

Comment: You need to use AJAX.

Comment: @Scimonster Ok but I don't know ajax. Can you tell me a specific function of ajax which I can use here?

Comment: Can you please tell me where this JS code you have placed I mean in .js file of any PHP Web Page(.php file)?

Answer (score 0):

Can't use both PHP and Javascript same time. **AJAX** is solution you want. Like:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  var needToConfirm = true;

  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    if (needToConfirm)
    {

      $.post('test.php','',function(res){
          //check here response       
      });

      return  'Are you sure?';


     }
     else 
     return 'Continue';
  }
```

Code of **test.php**:

```
echo $flag;// what ever it is true or false
```

Comment: i guess you're overthinking this. OP need a conditinal depending on the current view, not on some server response

Comment: @lordvlad op want to check flag variable so op can check in back-end an get response in **AJAX**

Comment: you cant use ajax for `window.onbeforeunload`, because ajax is async while onbeforeunload is sync

Comment: I am confused about the ajax code. Sorry I'm really a noob here. Can someone explain it?

Comment: @Manwal if you know what `window.onbeforeunload` does, you'll know that there is no point in making an ajax call (not for a beginner at least)

Comment: You could make a synchronous AJAX (SJAX?) call.

Comment: @Scimonster thats why I said 'not for an beginner'. besides, @manwal did not mention the need to make `$.post` synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs on the browser. And PHP on the server. The server returns the page to the client. Therefore, there is no way you can accomplish this.

You can use AJAX for this sort of a functionality.

Comment: `window.alert("<?=$someString ?>")` proves you wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing right, you want to show the user a message box where he has to confirm that he truly wants to leave your page, but only, if a specific PHP variable is set, right? You don't need AJAX for that.

```
<?php if ($needToConfirm === true) { ?>

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'are you sure?';
}

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need Ajax for it (but my solution is kinda dirty :) )

First, have PHP function to return you a value. There is example from my Google maps API project:

```
function nullate($data){
  if (empty($data)){
  echo "0";
  }
  else{
  echo $data;
 }
}
```

And later in the body you can do

```
 <body onload="initialize(<? nullate($_POST['north']);?>,<? nullate($_POST['east']);?>)">
```

I know its dirty nasty ugly line. So to make sure. I am `POST`ing data to my beautiful Google Maps API page, but this construct checks, if there was actually something sent

and then google maps javascript function:

```
function initialize(lat,lng) {
if (lat==0 && lng==0){
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.53233919502811, 17.02880859375);
}
else{
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
}
//....
}
```

So, in your case, the condition outcome must be `echo`ed to the javascript function

Comment: this is too much info and not at all helpful for a beginner